# Keeping Values connected when sorting results of a for loop

Tags: python

I am having an issue keeping values associated with their counterparts during certain parts of this code. I am trying to only print out the ticket code with the lowest priority. The first issue I had was that when someone does not enter a priority it defaults to "None". So after i filtered that out I wanted to put the remaining data into a list and then grab the min priority from that list and print it along with its ticket code.

The data set looks like :

```
ticket    ticket code                 ticket priority
100_400   100_400 ticket description        None
100_400   100_400 ticket description         5
100_400   100_400 ticket description         1
100_400   100_400 ticket description         2
100_400   100_400 ticket description         4
100_400   100_400 ticket description         3
```

So currently this is what my code looks like:

```
result = set()   
for ticket in tickets:
# to get rid of the "None" priorities
    if ticket.priority != '<pirority range>':
        print ""
    else:
        #this is where i need help keeping the priority and the ticket.code together
        result.add(ticket.priority)

print min(result) 
print ticket.code
```

Comment: What is `ticket`? Is it instance of some class?

Comment: What should happen if 2 tickets have the same priority?  Should that be impossible?  What if all the tickets you get are `None`?

Comment: It is possible to get two tickets of the same priority and if all tickets are none i have it to print "there are no ticket descriptions with priority set for this ticket"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the entire `ticket` to your `result` list rather than just the priority, and then implement your own `min` function. Also, depending on the rest of your application, considering using a different structure than `set` for result?

```
# this computes the minimum priority of a ticket
def ticketMin (list):
    min = list[0]
    for ticket in list:
        if (ticket.priority < min.priority):
            min = ticket
    return min

# changed set to list
result = list()   
for ticket in tickets:
# to get rid of the "None" priorities
    if ticket.priority != '<pirority range>':
        print ""
    else:
        #notice the change below
        result.append(ticket)

# changed 'min' to 'ticketMin'
minTicket = ticketMin(result)

print minTicket.priority
print minTicket.code
```

Alternatively, you could save a few lines and use the built in function with a Lambda, as Oscar illustrated in the comments:

```
# changed set to list
result = list()   
for ticket in tickets:
# to get rid of the "None" priorities
    if ticket.priority != '<pirority range>':
        print ""
    else:
        #notice the change below
        result.append(ticket)

# Oscar's solution:
minTicket = min(result, key=lambda val : val.priority)

print minTicket.priority
print minTicket.code
```

Comment: This solution reinvents the wheel by defining a `ticketMin` function, the practical approach here would be to use the `min` built-in function, like in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Add *tickets* to the `result` set, not their priorities. Then find the ticket with the minimum priority among those in the set, like this:

```
minTicket = min(result, key=lambda x : x.priority)
```